# Retrieve data from two different rows in a single SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table with the following data

[image]

and I need to find the number of minutes between two jobs (Say A and C).

The following query works but wondering, if there is a simpler way to achieve the same.

```
  DECLARE @StartTime datetime
    Declare @EndTime datetime
    set @StartTime = (SELECT start_time from table where jobname = 'A' )
    set @EndTime = (SELECT end_time from table where  jobname = 'C' )
    select datediff(minute,@StartTime, @EndTime) numberOfMinutes
```

Comment: Please follow the guidelines @ https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for titling your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sql Server's [*window functions*](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/) `LEAD` and `LAG` to get access to two rows in one SELECT statement.

Here's just one way to get the results you're after:

```sql
DECLARE @jobs TABLE
(
    Job char(1) primary key,
    Start_time datetime,
    End_time datetime
);

INSERT @jobs VALUES
('A', '2020/01/10 8:00', '2020/01/10 8:15'),
('B', '2020/01/10 8:15', '2020/01/10 8:17'),
('C', '2020/01/10 8:17', '2020/01/10 8:19'),
('D', '2020/01/10 8:19', '2020/01/10 8:53');

SELECT Job,
    Start_time,
    [Other job],
    [Other job's end time],
    DATEDIFF(mi, Start_time, [Other job's end time]) [Diff (min)]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Job, 
        Start_time,
        LEAD(Job, 2) OVER (ORDER BY Start_time) [Other job],
        LEAD(End_time, 2) OVER (ORDER BY Start_time) [Other job's end time]
    FROM @jobs
) AS data
WHERE [Other job] IS NOT NULL
```

Which shows:

```
Job  Start_time              Other job Other job's end time    Diff (min)
---- ----------------------- --------- ----------------------- -----------
A    2020-01-10 08:00:00.000 C         2020-01-10 08:19:00.000 19
B    2020-01-10 08:15:00.000 D         2020-01-10 08:53:00.000 38
```

You can output the difference between two specific jobs by filtering appropriately:

```sql
SELECT Job,
    Start_time,
    [Other job],
    [Other job's end time],
    DATEDIFF(mi, Start_time, [Other job's end time]) [Diff (min)]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Job, 
        Start_time,
        LEAD(Job) OVER (ORDER BY Start_time) [Other job],
        LEAD(End_time) OVER (ORDER BY Start_time) [Other job's end time]
    FROM @jobs
    WHERE Job IN ('A', 'C')
) AS data
WHERE Job = 'A'
```

Which shows:

```
Job  Start_time              Other job Other job's end time    Diff (min)
---- ----------------------- --------- ----------------------- -----------
A    2020-01-10 08:00:00.000 C         2020-01-10 08:19:00.000 19
```